# How do I use URL directories as variables?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm wondering how sites like Pastebin and Twitter pass (what I assume to be) variables via the URL.

For example, take a Pastebin URL. It has the format of `http://www.pastebin.com/<PASTE_UID>`. I'm wondering how they parse the UID without the server trying to treat it like an actual page. I can't imagine they generate individual files for each post.

I know this is most likely a combination of mod_rewrite and parsing the variable from the URL on the backend to extract the variable, but I'm at a loss on how to do it.

Comment: you're wondering how, yet you tagged this as `mod-rewrite` lol

Comment: @magneticstain still alive ?!

Comment: I knew it had something to do with mod_rewrite, just not exactly how to do it heh. Guess I didn't know what I already knew :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you can use apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), i.e.:

Create an `.htaccess` file on the root of your website with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^uid/(.*)$ /uid.php?uid=$1 [NC]
```

If, for example, the url is http://yoursite.com/uid/123456, apache will send the value `123456` via `$_GET` request to `uid.php`, you can get the uid value using:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['uid'])){
  $uid = $_GET['uid'];
  //123456 
}
?>
```

Comment: Why do you call `empty()` all in uppercase? It's recommended to use the function name as it is defined: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: @Rizier123 It's an old habit, and, asa know, php functions are case insensitive but I agree with you, "__it is usually good form to call functions as they appear in their declaration__".

Comment: Read ^ the note half way down in the manual page..

Comment: brain input done! tks for pointing that :)

Comment: Of course! Guess I just needed a bit more clarification. Thank you!